# Vitest - How do I get Jest compatible coverage summary in json?

Tags: github-actions, vitest

I read the documents,

- https://vitest.dev/guide/coverage.html
- https://vitest.dev/config/

The documents say that config reporters json is for “give a simple JSON summary”,
but output only includes test results like junit xml.

How do I get Jest compatible json summary?

Because I use MishaKav/jest-coverage-comment in GitHub Action, the action needs Jest compatible json summary.
The options “junit-xmlpath” and “coverage-path” works fine.

I tried to use “coverage/coverage-final.json”,
but return error.

```
Error: Parse summary report. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lines')
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the test-reporter (which you configured with `--reporter`) for test results and the [coverage-reporter](https://vitest.dev/config/#coverage-reporter) which you should configure with `--coverage.reporter`. You'll need to also `npm install -D @vitest/coverage-v8` for this coverage reporter to work. This is what i use for the MishaKav/jest-coverage-comment action to work:

```
vitest run --coverage.enabled --reporter=junit --coverage.reporter=json-summary
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add --reporter=json and the magic will happen.
Tal

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).